# Get different content length using Java API to read data from Google Cloud Storage(GCS) in many times

Tags: java, google-app-engine, curl, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to implement a download feature to read data from Google Cloud Storage in Google App Engine with Java API. But I got different content-length during many times test. The following is my code. Does anyone encounter same symptom like this?

```
public static void outputToServletResponse(String bucketName, String objectName, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    Storage client = getService();
    Storage.Objects.Get getObject = client.objects().get(bucketName, objectName);
    resp.setContentType(getObject.execute().getContentType());
    getObject.getMediaHttpDownloader().setDirectDownloadEnabled(!IS_APP_ENGINE);
    getObject.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(resp.getOutputStream());
}
```

Here is my curl test, the file size is 34 bytes

```html
    #1st test

curl -v http://elifepower2015-test.appspot.com/gcsReadTest?filename=test
*   Trying 74.125.204.141...
* Connected to elifepower2015-test.appspot.com (74.125.204.141) port 80 (#0)
> GET /gcsReadTest?filename=test HTTP/1.1
> Host: elifepower2015-test.appspot.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.42.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Date: Fri, 08 Jan 2016 11:44:09 GMT
< Server: Google Frontend
**< Content-Length: 16**
< 
aaaaaaaa
* Connection #0 to host elifepower2015-test.appspot.com left intact
bbbbbbb

#2nd test
curl -v http://elifepower2015-test.appspot.com/gcsReadTest?filename=test
*   Trying 74.125.204.141...
* Connected to elifepower2015-test.appspot.com (74.125.204.141) port 80 (#0)
> GET /gcsReadTest?filename=test HTTP/1.1
> Host: elifepower2015-test.appspot.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.42.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Date: Fri, 08 Jan 2016 11:44:15 GMT
< Server: Google Frontend
**< Content-Length: 34**
< 
aaaaaaaa
bbbbbbb
cccccccc
```

Comment: Unless the file is changing, this deserves posting to the [Public Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list). If you post there, we will quickly pick up the issue and investigate it, or at the least ask for more relevant information.

Comment: Thanks! I will move this question to the Public Issue Tracker.